# Recreate this preloading screen--looks like a gif not a coded animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Coding newb here!
I've been trying to recreate this preloading screen (http://addpbj.com ) for hours but I can't seem to get it right. All the tutorials online are showing how to make animated spinners and loaders, but I like the logo throb. I feel like I am going about this the wrong way. I've been trying to make the attached gif my preloading screen. 
This is my code so far:

```
    <div id="dvLoading"></div>
*/----CSS----/*
   #dvLoading{
    background:#000       url(https://media.giphy.com/media/l4JyJHAF8blvfplf2/source.gif) no-repeat center center;
  display: blocks;
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
   margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}
*/----JQ----/*
        $(window).load(function(){
       $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
    });
```

[(http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJGPQG)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MJGPQG). Is there something wrong with the jquery?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply a scale and opacity loop.

```css
body{
  background: #ed4424;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-animation: THROB 8s infinite;
  -moz-animation:    THROB 8s infinite;
  -o-animation:      THROB 8s infinite;
  animation:         THROB 8s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes THROB {
  0%   { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  50%  { opacity: 0.4; transform: scale(0.7) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes THROB {
  0%   { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  50%  { opacity: 0.4; transform: scale(0.7) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
@-o-keyframes THROB {
  0%   { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  50%  { opacity: 0.4; transform: scale(0.7) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
@keyframes THROB {
  0%   { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  50%  { opacity: 0.4; transform: scale(0.7) translate(-50%,-50%); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1) translate(-50%,-50%); }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/56d8893cb09f9547596ab9f7/t/56d9a10fe707eb99e3cf68c3/1485878555441/?format=1500w">
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you Serg. Now, to plug it into the site so it only appears when things are loading & it disappears after, all I will need is to adapt the JS?   var preload = document.getElementById("overlay");
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  overlay.style.display = 'none';
})

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Man.